# Flattening Future[EitherT[Future, A, B]]

Tags: scala, scalaz

As the title mentions.

Having many operations done using `EitherT[Future, A, B]`. Sometimes I want map left or right through another operation having signature `A => Future[C]`. Other scenario is that `EitherT[Future, A, B]` the result of a mapping over a future resulting `Future[EitherT[Future, A, B]]`.

How can I elegantly flatten types like:

`EitherT[Future, Future[A], Future[B]]` and `Future[EitherT[Future, A, B]]`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all your cases you can use `EitherT#flatMap` (or `EitherT#flatMapF`), in combination with lifting some value to `EitherT` (or disjunction (`\/`) with `flatMapF`).

- Mapping a `B => F[C]` over an `EitherT[F, A, B]` :

  `flatMap` + lift

  ```
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  import scalaz._, Scalaz._

  def f(i: Int): Future[Double] = Future.successful(i.toDouble)
  val r = EitherT.right[Future, String, Int](Future.successful(1))

  r.flatMap(i => EitherT.right(f(i)))
  // or
  r.flatMapF(i => f(i).map(_.right))
  ```
- Mapping a `A => F[C]` over an `EitherT[F, A, B]` :

  `swap` + `flatMap` + lift

  ```
  def g(s: String): Future[Int] = Future.successful(s.length)

  val l = EitherT.left[Future, String, Int](Future.successful("error"))

  l.swap.flatMap(s => EitherT.right(g(s))).swap
  // or
  l.swap.flatMap(s => EitherT.left[Future, Int, Int](g(s)))
  // or
  l.swap.flatMapF(s => g(s).map(_.left))
  ```
- Mapping an `A => Either[F, B, C]` to an `F[A]` :

  lift + `flatMap`

  ```
  def h(i: Int): EitherT[Future, String, Int] = 
    EitherT.right(Future.successful(i + 1))

  val fut = Future.successful(1)

  // mapping gives us Future[EitherT[Future, String, Int]]
  fut.map(h)                    

  // lifting to EitherT and flatMap gives us EitherT[Future, String, Int]
  EitherT.right(fut).flatMap(h)
  ```